# Wireless card soft blocked ath9k

Tags: wireless, atheros

So i'm a new user to Linux and downloaded the Wubi installer of 11.10. Unfortunately, it's been a month and I still cannot figure out how to change my wireless soft blocked to No. I cannot get online at all and it's really hindering what I can do with 11.10.

any suggestions would be very very much appreciated

-johnny

Answer (score 1):

```
rfkill unblock X
```

where X is the number next to your phy0 for rfkill list

Comment: you might also be having this problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62730/cannot-change-soft-block-setting-to-no-for-wireless but there wasn't that much detail in the question