# soft-blocked on my wireless interfaces

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, centrino, rfkill

I have a new laptop with a centrino wireless card.

I installed ubuntu on it and all seemed fine until I upgraded the kernel, and rebooted.

My wireless stopped working despite toggling the wireless button.

rfkill list returns the following:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1:hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

the hardware switch only toggles the hard blocks.

How do I turn off the software blocks? I have tried

```
rfkill unblock all
```

without success. What next?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/q/62730/83046) might help. Also, please mention which laptop you are using?

Answer (score 0):

sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi 
cd /etc/modprobe.d
sudo nano blacklist.conf
In that config file, just add
blacklist acer-wmi

Just use these commands and reboot. thats it