# Wireless not working - ASUS X450J - Qualcomm Atheros

Tags: wireless, atheros

I just did a clean install, overwriting my old Windows. I'm pretty much a novice and don't know where to start. I've tried reading a few answers that seemed relevant but find it all a bit confusing, the people asking seem to have a better grasp on using terminal code etc than I do and I don't want to take any risks.

Currently, I'm doing a full update using an ethernet cable - hoping that might fix it but suspect from the questions I've seen on my adapter it probably won't.

My wireless adapter is a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter.

When I go into the network setting and try to turn on the wireless it turns on for half a second then turns off.

Bearing in mind I am a complete novice, is anyone able to assist in getting the wireless working?

Hardware details:

```
connor@connor-X450JF:~$ sudo lspci -nn 
[sudo] password for connor: 
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0c04] (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller [8086:0c01] (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:8c14] (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:8c16] (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller [8086:8c49] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:8c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 745M] [10de:0fe3] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
```

`rfkill list`

```
connor@connor-X450JF:~$ rfkill list
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

UPD: Tried `rfkill unblock 0` no output to report, wireless still cannot be enabled

Tried `rfkill unblock acer-wireless`gave output `Bogus unblock argument 'acer-wireless'.`

UPD: Installed Ubuntu 13.10 from the website - here is the output from `if config`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d0:2b:e7:1f:8c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:882 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:882 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:84283 (84.2 KB)  TX bytes:84283 (84.2 KB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:b6:e0:ab:ce:3a  
          inet addr:192.168.42.17  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f8b6:e0ff:feab:ce3a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2754 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:2
          TX packets:2673 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2204062 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:488800 (488.8 KB)
```

Here's `iwconfig`

```
usb0      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

The `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

So I ran `sudo rfkill unblock all` and nothing happened:

```
connor@connor:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all
connor@connor:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

UPD: Using [this troubleshooting guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Commands#lshw)  I ran `sudo lshw`

Here is the output:

```
configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f79fffff
           *-network DISABLED
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 01
                serial: 24:fd:52:79:9c:53
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
```

I can't make heads or tails of it. Anyone else? Is `driver=pcieport` even a driver?

A million rep points from me for Danatela - how can I reward this wonderful human being for all his/her help?

Comment: OK, thank you for taking the time @Danatela - I understand you are a volunteer and I appreciate what you do

Comment: @ChrisR. asks: A soft block is usually the wireless being switched off on by the keyboard. Is there a function key that turns the wireless on off (usually looks like a radio tower with radio waves coming from it)?

Comment: Well, I did soft block my wireless once, this is the link for how I solved it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62730/cannot-change-soft-block-setting-to-no-for-wireless

Comment: Keyboard button doesn't work

Comment: @mmm3743 How do I "save"? I pasted the code line by line as per the first reply but the commands at the end had no option for saving?

Comment: ZOMFG!!!!!! IT WORKED!!!

Comment: Somebody award @mmm3743 his +100 rep points!!!

Comment: @mmm3743 please return your wonderful answer and you will get +100 rep

Comment: @ConnorJ: If you want reward me, then please consider marking my answer as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `rfkill list`

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

If it shows some devices are soft-blocked, run `rfkill unblock ID` where ID is number of device. For you solution is to run:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Also try to switch aerial on/off using keyboard. On my notebook it sometimes helps. I use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> chord. And the icon looks like threetheethed fork or like the radio – as ChrisR. says.

If it shows that device is hard-blocked, you should unplug your notebook, remove the battery, then press and hold the power button for a while, then try it.

### THE SOLUTION

with credits to [mmm3743](https://askubuntu.com/users/162476/mmm3743) and [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom)

from [Cannot change soft block setting to "no" for AR9287 Wireless Network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62730/cannot-change-soft-block-setting-to-no-for-wireless)

Copy and paste (line by line) the following into a terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
cd /etc/modprobe.d
sudo nano blacklist.conf
```

Then add `blacklist acer-wmi` as a new line at the end of the file.

Save and reboot.

Comment: Updated original - it said "bogus" unblock argument for ID.

Also, the device is inside my laptop so won't be able to do a hard reset like you describe

Comment: No hard block on the rfkill list, there is a soft block though - see original post

Comment: Would you believe the laptop has an inbuilt battery that I can't remove, lol?

I tried the unblock acer-wireless, it still says bogus argument

Comment: No output - still can't enable wireless

Comment: No output doesn't mean rfkill failed it means something else is broken.

Comment: @Danatela - no output, still can't enable wireless

Comment: @Danatela version 12.04

I tried sudo with the other rfkill unblock options you suggested earlier, no love

Comment: The only option you have now is to [file a bugreport](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) and try 13.10.

Comment: Lol, I should have guessed this was never going to be easy ;)

I'm going to try 13, will let you know how it goes

Comment: What a fat load of fail Ubuntu turned out to be - v. 13 won't even install.

Comment: I don't even know, it was just a black screen with a wall of text and the install wouldn't go any further.

I'm so lost now, I don't know what to do, I want to cry.

Comment: There's a file in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf that says:

"# For some Atheros 5K RF MACs, the madwifi driver loads buts fails to
# correctly initialize the hardware, leaving it in a state from
# which ath5k cannot recover. To prevent this condition, stop
# madwifi from loading by default. Use Jockey to select one driver
# or the other. (Ubuntu: #315056, #323830)
blacklist ath_pci"

Might this work? And if so, how would I do it?

Comment: Then `sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk`.

Comment: @Danatela I tried again. Now the screen just goes black, no error messages. Just nothing.

I'm going to have to try and download Windows 7 - FML

Comment: @ConnorJ Don't give up. Read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

Comment: @danatela I disabled secure boot in the BIOS, got 13 installed - going to run through the troubleshooting steps you walked me through earlier

Comment: @hbdgaf, I started a bounty, you can try to make your answer

Answer (score 2):

Is the module asus_nb_wmi loaded? Check:

```
#lsmod | grep asus
```

If so, please try a driver parameter:

```
#sudo -i
#echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
#exit
```

Reboot and see if the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> behavior is changed. If not, try the sequence above again, but with the integer 1 or then 4.

Comment: Nope.

I tried "1" because that's the output from the lsmod | grep asus command. WHICH IT DOES NOW!!! W00000!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that my answer will definitely work but you can give it a try. Actually the wireless problem has become a common problem in Ubuntu 12.04 and it happened with me too when I installed Ubuntu 12.04. Here is what I did to make it working:

1. First connect with any wired Internet connection or USB Dongle; It will be needed to download the drivers and it is only one time work.
2. Open terminal and execute this command:

   ```
   sudo jockey-gtk
   ```

   this application will search for all available drivers and try to download and install if missing.
3. Once successfully finished, you'll get that some wireless drives has been installed. Just restart your system once.

Hope it works for you too. Reply what happens!