# How do I create a system file /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf?

Tags: networking, drivers, configuration, atheros

My wireless adapter (atheros) will not work - I've tried extensive troubleshooting with @danatela (bless his/her heart) here:

[Wireless not working - ASUS X450J - Qualcomm Atheros](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440158/wireless-not-working-asus-x450j-qualcomm-atheros)

but it failed. Other answered questions refer to [this post on crunchbang](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=17833)

But I have no idea how to create a file in this directory - I don't have permissions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Answer (score 2):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

The text editor *gedit* will open a new empty file. Add a single line:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

Proofread, save and close *gedit*. Now load the module immediately:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

The conf file you wrote will cause the parameter *nohwcrypt=1* to now be automatically be loaded on boot.

Comment: What does "load the module" mean?

Comment: It means that you want the driver _ath9k_ to be loaded into the system but with a driver parameter nohwcrypt=1. Ordinarily, after you have written the conf file, it will only be applied on boot. By unloading _ath9k_ and reloading it with nohwcrypt=1 immediately, there is no need to reboot to apply and test it.

Comment: Is `nohwcrypt=1` really necessary in `sudo modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1` ? Shouldn't the config file be read  with `sudo modprobe ath9k` where that option already exists ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Not strictly, but it can't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is open your file browser with root (administrator) privaledges. To do this, open terminal (ctrl+alt+t), and type:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

This will open a file manager, you can do all the file managing you need to do (do not close terminal until you have closed the file manager).

**WARNING** Running programs with sudo can be dangerious. It basically gives them access to all of your computer. Do not open just any program with sudo!

**EDIT:
The old answer said to run 'sudo nautilus' This is not a good idea according to [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)! Whenever running graphical applications with sudo, use gksudo or kdesudo instead of sudo(see the link for more details).**

Comment: How does this anwer the question?

Comment: With nautilus run a sudo, he can navigate to the directory he wants, and create the file he wants.

Comment: I was bragged away by the other posted answer, will clean up the comment mess soon. Sorry for the distraction.