# Why my Ubuntu block wlan & how to unblock?

Tags: boot, networking, wireless, drivers, rfkill

**Everytime I boot Ubuntu, my wifi lan is Soft-blocked.** ( I did `rfkill list`, `rfkill unblock wlan` to verify the case. In addition I note that it is blocked some seconds after boot is finished).

**how can I avoid this please** ? What should I do to not block wlan ? Where is the thing to uncheck, to avoid this blocking ?

**DRIVER** it is `iwlwifi`.

**NOTE**
In `rc/local`, I have added this:

```
rfkill unblock wlan
ifconnfig wlan0 up
```

But uit still results in the same state. **Like if the `rfkill block wlan` is called seconds after `rc.local`.**

Answer (score 1):

---

Your wifi might be disable for several reasons. I suggest you look into the logs (`journalctl -b -0` if you use a recent version of Ubuntu).

This might be a problem with your `network-manager` configuration (assuming you use `network-manager` to access Internet, which is the default in Ubuntu), which can be found in the folder `/var/lib/NetworkManager/`.

**EDIT:**
It can also be a problem with your kernel driver. I found that on this site: [Cannot change soft block setting to "no" for AR9287 Wireless Network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62730/cannot-change-soft-block-setting-to-no-for-ar9287-wireless-network).

Comment: Thank you. Actually `journalctl` does not exist on my system. Really I'm not Ubuntu but Mint 17.2

Comment: Then you can have a look at `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/messages.log` (or any other file in `/var/log` depending on your configuration). The command `journalctl` is now standard in most recent Linux distributions, but it is optional Linux Mint.

Comment: How will it help his wireless to work properly by *blacklisting* the driver??

Comment: It won't, thank you for pointing that out. I edited my post. Actually, the logs should be the easiest way to figure out what happens.