Ubuntu 24.10 Keeps Blocking Wifi, How to Unblock permanently
I recently updated from 24.04 to 24.10 and I have been having nothing but problems with it not recognizing WIFI. Prior to the update it had no issues whatsoever.
I eventually tracked down the problem though where I have to just input:  rfkill unblock all  in order for the WIFI to be recognized.
Is there an easy way to make this solution permanent? It is kind of annoying to have to do every time I restart the laptop.

You probably should try to find out why it is blocked, Post the results of 'journalctl -b -0' when it occurs.  See the following link for more information.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/667722/why-my-ubuntu-block-wlan-how-to-unblock

Sorry, I used 'journalctl -b -0' but after scrolling through four thousand of lines of code, and still not getting past the install date of Ubuntu, I think I need a little bit more information about what I am looking for.
